# Billboard facing the camera has wrong rotation near 180 degrees

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, lwjgl, particles

I've implemented a particle system. I'm drawing their textures on billboards that should be rotated towards the camera.

This works fine except for the case when the angle between particle->camera and the normal comes near to 180 degrees. Then the particle starts rotating around itself many times.

The angle is calculated using cos(angle) = dot(a, b) / (length(a) * length(b),  the length are both 1 cause the Vectors are normalized.
The axis is calculated using the cross product of those two vectors.

```
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    //calculate rotation
    Vector3f normal = new Vector3f(0, 0, 1);
    Vector3f dir = Vector3f.sub(new Vector3f(GraphicsData.camera.x, GraphicsData.camera.y, GraphicsData.camera.z), new Vector3f(x, y, z), null);
    if(dir.length() == 0)
    {
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        return;
    }
    dir = (Vector3f) dir.normalise();
    float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(Vector3f.dot(normal, dir)));
    Vector3f rotationAxis = Vector3f.cross(normal, dir, null);
    rotationAxis = (Vector3f) rotationAxis.normalise();
    System.out.println("Angle: + " + angle + "    Axis: " + rotationAxis);


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ParticleEngine.particleTextures.get(typeId).texture.getTextureID());


    glColor4f(1f,1f,1f, time >= lifeTime - decayTime ? ((float)lifeTime - (float)time) / ((float)lifeTime - (float)decayTime) : 1f);
    shaderEngine.createModelMatrix(new Vector3f(x, y, z), new Vector3f(angle * rotationAxis.x, angle * rotationAxis.y, angle * rotationAxis.z), new Vector3f(sx, sy, sz));
    shaderEngine.loadModelMatrix(shaderEngine.particle);
    glCallList(ParticleEngine.particleTextures.get(typeId).displayListId + textureIndex);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

What am i doing wrong calculating the rotation?

```
public static void createModelMatrix(Vector3f pos, Vector3f rot, Vector3f scale)
{
    GraphicsData.camera.modelMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    GraphicsData.camera.modelMatrix.setIdentity();
    GraphicsData.camera.modelMatrix.translate(pos);
    GraphicsData.camera.modelMatrix.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rot.x), new Vector3f(1,0,0));
    GraphicsData.camera.modelMatrix.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rot.y), new Vector3f(0,1,0));
    GraphicsData.camera.modelMatrix.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rot.z), new Vector3f(0,0,1));
    GraphicsData.camera.modelMatrix.scale(scale);
}
```

Comment: When the normal and dir vectors are parallel then the cross product of them will be zero and your rotationAxis vector will be zero. As you get close to this value rotationAxis will be very small and normalization might produce unreliable values due to floating point errors etc.

Comment: That's a very good idea but why isn't this the case when the angle is going near 0. Then the sin(angle) is going towards 0, too.  I've prinited the angels and the axis vector and there are about 8 digits of precision at 178 degrees, the problem starts at around 170 degrees

Answer (score 0):

More a long comment or perhaps a partial answer to the problem:

If you are computing the cross product anyway, then use that

```
norm( a × b ) = sin(angle) * norm(a)*norm(b)
dot(a,b)      = cos(angle) * norm(a)*norm(b)
```

to determine

```
angle = atan2( norm(a×b), dot(a,b) )
```

Comment: norm(a x b) is a vector, not a number. Should i use the length?

Comment: a x b is the vector, the norm of it is the length.

Comment: @LutzL norm(a x b) is (a x b) / length(a x b) and therefore a vector.

Comment: I think we are mixing concepts. I speak of the mathematical concept of a norm, you of the normalization function for a vector.

Comment: @LutzL You're right, I didn't know [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) is used for the length of a vector in mathematics. But maybe you should use length instead, because in this case it can be misunderstood as [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector), especially because LWJGL's util functions are called like that.